# PHP, Eclipse/Zend Studio & Debugging with expressions

Tags: php, eclipse, debugging, zend-studio, expression

I have a variable in my PHP application that changes often, I'd like to debug so that it keeps executing until the variable changes to a specific value (in this case boolean true). I've heard this could be done with expressions? True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a conditional breakpoint. Set breakpoint in editor by clicking on gutter. Then right-click it and type condition in PHP.